# Use image from url as R.drawable.image in method

Tags: android, android-drawable

I just install  `dev-labs-bg /fullscreen-video-view`  from GitHub and I want to set thumbnail, but the library method use only images from drawable.

```
val thumbnailResId = R.drawable.video_thumbnail

fullscreenVideoView.videoUrl(videoUrl)
    .thumbnail(thumbnailResId)
```

How I can use image from URL to load into that method.Any clue or this is not postible

Comment: Not possible . look for a method which accept a `Bitmap` or you can create one by yourself..

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported. I've checked the newest API by myself and can confirm that no method that supports `Bitmap` or `Drawable` exists. Here is the snippet from the documentation as a confirmation:
`This feature supports loading only drawables from the Android project.` Source: https://github.com/dev-labs-bg/fullscreen-video-view#add-thumbnail

Comment: If I made overrated method which accept Bitmap can be done?

Comment: You can try with the fork of the library and then create an additional method accepting `Drawable` or `Bitmap` objects. You should be able to do that because the thumbnail is an ImageView in the library. I encourage you to create a pull request after adding this method - this will definitely help the developers' community :)